# Multiple field phrase query in Lucene 7.1.0 with optional wildcards allowed

Tags: java, search, lucene

**I have indexed some Wikipedia URLs along with the contents of these pages. I would like to be able to search through both of these fields simultaneously or search by only one field with an additional option to allow wildcards on any given field** (although I am not sure if I would ever use a wildcard option on the content input), so I can not only find

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_songs_(Chopin)

but I can also find

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric_Chopin

I have Lucene version 7.1.0 and couldn't completely grasp the documentation, so I did a thorough search on SO and based my code on the following Q&A (mostly from the old Lucene versions, but the functionalities seem to be the same):

[Exact Phrase search using Lucene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527868/exact-phrase-search-using-lucene)

[How to do a Multi field - Phrase search in Lucene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100528/how-to-do-a-multi-field-phrase-search-in-lucene)

[Phrase query in Lucene 6.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41590509/phrase-query-in-lucene-6-2-0)

[How to match exact text in Lucene search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37495639/how-to-match-exact-text-in-lucene-search?rq=1)

Based on the answers above, I came up with some ideas on how to conduct a search using the following input:

Assumptions:

```
Query q;
QueryParser qp;

/* I think this is fishy but do not know how to do it differently */
if (contentOnlySearch) {
  qp = new QueryParser("content", analyzer);
} else {
  qp = new QueryParser("url", analyzer);
}
/* end */

String urlQuery = "chopin";
String contentQuery = "polish songs that chopin wrote";
if (allowUrlQueryWildcards) {
  urlQuery = "*" + urlQuery + "*";
}
if (allowContentQueryWildcards) {
  contentQuery = "*" + contentQuery + "*";
}
```

Idea 1:

```
q = MultiFieldQueryParser.parse(
  new String[] {urlQuery, contentQuery},
  new String[] {"url", "content"},
  analyzer
);
```

Idea 2:

```
q = qp.parse("url:\"" + urlQuery + "\" AND content:\"" + contentQuery + "\"");
```

**1. Now, both of these approaches along with some others failed miserably, I was either getting an error or most often finding a website which does not contain the input contentQuery. What am I doing wrong?**

**Side questions:**

**2. If I have around 10000 URLs saved, is allowing wildcards a good choice here, or should I tweak the indexing/searching process a bit to be able to find both these URLs by inputting "Chopin"?**

**3. Why does lucene find and index "Chopin" in "(Chopin)", but not in "_Chopin"?**

PS. I come from JavaScript, I hope my Java code is correct and does not cause your eyes to bleed.